# how can i allocate memory for a union member that haven't been initialized

Tags: c++, memory, vector, unions

I have got a union of two members.

```
union myUnion {
    std::wstring mem1;
    int mem2;
    myUnion(std::wstring in){
        this->mem1 = in;
    }
    myUnion(int in){
        this->mem2 = in;
    }
    myUnion(const myUnion& in){
        if(this->mem2){
            this->mem2 = in.mem2;
        }else{
            this->mem1 = in.mem1;
        }
    }
};
//and then I make a vector out of the union:
std::vector<myUnion> unions;
//but when I try to push_back:
unions.push_back(L"A");
```

it soon breaks out a run time error:
    0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC.
and when I try to debug this program, I realize that mem1 have not been allocate a memory. I really don't know why this happens and I want to know how can i fix it.

Comment: You'll need to put your union in a struct with another member indicating which member of the union is active. Only one member of a union can have a value at a time.

Comment: Note that when following Dan's suggestion (which is a good one), the best approach is to make the union be *anonymous*, i.e. remove the name `myUnion`. This allows the outer object's constructor and other special functions to do the initialization. Your best bet here is to consult a working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, `union` is not a very natural datatype, because it doesn't really fit naturally with the whole C++ idea of constructors and destructors. When you create a union in C++, it does not call constructors for any of its possible types, because they would all be writing on top of eachother.

So this constructor

```
myUnion(std::wstring in){
    this->mem1 = in;
}
```

will crash because `this->mem1`'s lifetime as a string has not been started. You would have to use something like, call `std::string` ctor using placement new at that address. Later, if you change the data type, you will have to make sure to remember to call the dtor for `this->mem1` also before you start writing to a different field of the union, or you will get memory leakage or corruption.

By far the simpler way to do what you are trying to do in C++ is to use a variant type like `boost::variant` which is going to handle all the boilerplate and all the details for you. (Union is okay if you are only using trivial types with no ctors or dtors.)

```
typedef boost::variant<std::wstring, int> MyUnion;

std::vector<MyUnion> unions;

unions.push_back(L"A");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor is broken as...

```
if(this->mem2){
```

...will return true for any `mem2` value other than `0`, and if the union was actually constructed with a string then `mem2` is the first `sizeof mem2` bytes from `mem1`: quite likely to be non-0.  If you want a union-like object to copy itself properly, you generally need to wrap it in an outer `struct` that adds some integral/enum type to keep track of the union's current datatype.  Other behaviours including your `myUnion(wstring)` constructor and destructor are also flawed.

Handling unions without invoking undefined behaviour is tricky - you're best off using `boost::variant` instead.